# Laptop Glitches/Freezes Every Second for A Fraction of a Second When Connected to WiFi

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, freeze

I can observe this effect when I keep clicking the volume slider so that it would keep making sound. When connected to WiFi, I can hear a buzz/clicking/clipping every second (the frequency is a bit higher than once per second) for a small fraction of a second. This is gone when I disconnect/disable WiFi.

I can also observe this when gaming. It seems that the graphics freezes for a fraction of a second every second or so. This is also gone when I disconnect/disable WiFi.

Restarting does not help.

My Laptop: Dell Inspiron 15 Gaming 7567; Windows 10 Home.

Thanks!

Comment: Try updating the drivers for your WiFi.

Comment: @Appleoddity I tried that, but for some reason I cannot install the newest driver. Log says (among other things) `ERROR_INSTALL_PLATFORM_UNSUPPORTED`. I am pretty sure I downloaded the right driver.

Comment: Your model can come Intel or Qualcomm (Atheros?) WiFi cards. Please double-check you're downloading the driver for your specific hardware and OS version.

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following two ways:

Way 1. **Unplug the wireless network card, then plug in the wireless network card.**

Way 2. **Reinstall the wireless network card driver**.

**First**, Uninstall the original wireless network card driver, then install the latest driver.

What driver do we try to install? (MS updates. Dell or OEM)

When the PC manufacture(Dell)'s driver is not supported for Windows 10, try to download and install the driver that your device(wireless adapter)'s original vendor, such as Intel, Realtek.

Be careful about vendor and model name of your device, i.e. identify it accurately.

We can get to know about your device, via Device Manager.

1. Open "Control Panel".
2. Select "System".
3. Select "Device Manager" on the left side.
4. Click "Network adapters".

**Second**, If we still can't install after uninstalling, try to reinstall the latest driver after reinstalling the operating system.